# Usage of Tasks vs Jobs in Concourse CI

Tags: continuous-integration, build-pipeline

I would like to know when it would be ideal to use Jobs over Tasks. What I mean is there are situations where we could run tasks within a job that are not dependant to each other in parallel, which I feel is the same as Running different Jobs. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Please add or expand your current rationale about this and it to the question, e.g. what is the difference between a job and a task? What do other resources say?

Comment: Basically in Concourse a Job is a group of tasks. However you can have a set of tasks that do not depend on each other run in parallel. To my understanding this is similar to having multiple jobs. Hence the doubt. Also splitting into jobs give a better visual display on the Concourse board than running tasks.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?